# Why is the StatusBar half the width of the window?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I've got a fairly minimal window defined in XAML. The `StatusBar` unfortunately takes only half the width, and doesn't stretch to the whole width of the window.

Why is that / how do I fix it?

```
<Window x:Class="TheProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TheProject"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="771.382">
    <DockPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" LastChildFill="False">
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="289,127,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="21">
            <StatusBarItem x:Name="actionStatus" Content="StatusBarItem"/>
        </StatusBar>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value of the `DockPanel.Dock` property is `Left`. That is why your `Button` (which comes first in the markup) is aligned left and then the remaining space to the right is used to align the other controls. Since you assign `Bottom` to the `StatusBar` (which comes second), it will be aligned at the bottom of the remaining space. **Order of controls matters** in a `DockPanel`.

You can test this by switching the order of the controls, which will align the `StatusBar` first.

```
<DockPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" LastChildFill="False">
   <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="21">
      <StatusBarItem x:Name="actionStatus" Content="StatusBarItem"/>
   </StatusBar>
   <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="289,127,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Another approach is to set the the `Dock` property on the `Button` to `Top`, which aligns it at the top and leaves the remaining space *below* it, which will align the `StatusBar` right, too.

```
<DockPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" LastChildFill="False">
   <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="289,127,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
   <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="21">
      <StatusBarItem x:Name="actionStatus" Content="StatusBarItem"/>
   </StatusBar>
</DockPanel>
```

---

Just as a note, there are certainly other options, too, like removing `LastChildFill="False"` and defining the button last, but that really depends on your requirements. The important bit to understand is how `DockPanel` divides space and in what order, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.dockpanel?view=net-5.0#remarks) for reference:

> The position of child elements of a `DockPanel` on the screen is determined by the `Dock` property of the respective child elements **and the relative order of those child elements under the `DockPanel`**. Therefore, a set of child elements with the same `Dock` property values can be positioned differently on the screen depending on the order of these children under the `DockPanel`. Child ordering effects positioning because the `DockPanel` iterates through its child elements in order, setting the position of each element **depending on remaining space**.